# Help me find my girlfriend!

Tags: cipher, steganography

All right... I admit it, I'm not great at puzzles. Someone kidnapped my girlfriend, but they left me a ransom message. I obviously don't have a million dollars, and I'm scared.. You seem to know what you're doing, though... can you folks help?
[image: The note in question]

Please... I need your help.

(The note is the only part of the puzzle. The rest is just for flavor.)

Comment: For a second there, I thought the title was *help me find a girlfriend*

Comment: The image without blue lines: http://i.imgur.com/KuvI27P.png

Comment: Hey. this is not a dating site.

Comment: @Marius, I wish that was made clear in the "Tour" page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The hidden message in the note reads:

> **Your girlfriend is safe and sound in the local library.**

Thanks to Rubio for transcribing the note. The ...

> ... message is hidden in the text with a Baconian cipher:
>
> ```
>     WeHAv eYOuR GirLF Riend anDSh eSgoi Ngtob eCoMe thEnE
>     Xtbig dEtec tiVec aSEun lesSY oUbri NgusA MillI ondol
>     laRsI naNun marke dENve lopET OtheC hURcH WekNO wYOur
>     enoTA nExpe rTPuz ZleRt hoUGH soWeh iDaCl uEToH erlOc
>     ation iNtHi sMeSs aGeif youcA Nread itcom Eandg EtHEr
> ```
>
> Small letters are treated as A, capital letters as B:
>
> ```
>     BaBBa aBBaB BaaBB Baaaa aaBBa aBaaa Baaaa aBaBa aaBaB
>     Baaaa aBaaa aaBaa aBBaa aaaBB aBaaa BaaaB BaaaB aaaaa
>     aaBaB aaBaa aaaaa aBBaa aaaBB BaaaB aBBaB BaaBB aBBaa
>     aaaBB aBaaa aBBaa BaaBa aaBBB aaBaa aBaBa aBBaB aaaBa
>     aaaaa aBaBa aBaBa aBaaa aaaaB Baaaa aaaaa Baaaa BaBBa
> ```
>
> These five-letter chunks can be decoded with the Baconian cipher, where the null-based positions of the letters in the alphabet are rendered as binary numbers, but with A and B instead of 0 and 1. The variant used here uses a single code for I and J as well as for U and V, so that the alphabet effectively has only 24 letters.
>
>  It turns out that the strange I in million isn't special, it's just acapital I. Perhaps it was used, because the capital I of the font looks more like a small ell.

Comment: Aaaah well done. I should have got this, because I pointed the OP to my cipher guide where I used this technique for the Baconian cipher example :P

Comment: There is a regular capital I in the text (dollaRs In...), so the special capital I is even weirder.

Comment: You got it! @ffao The special one was there so it didn't look like "Milllon" with three Ls.

Comment: but how would a not-so-expert puzzler find *this* out? ;)

Answer (score 3):

(Very partial answer)

> Transcribing the message, including upper/lowercase lettering from the original based on the font lettering shown [here](http://www.dafont.com/earwig-factory.font), gives:
>  We HAve YOuR GirLFRiend
>  anD She'S goiNg to beCome thE
>  nEXt big dEtectiVe caSE
>  unlesS YoU briNg us A Mill$\rm$***I***$\rm$on
>  dollaRs In aN unmarked
>  ENvelopE TO the ChURcH. We
>  kNOw YOu're noT An ExperT
>  PuzZleR thoUGH so We hiD a
>  CluE To Her lOcation iN tHis
>  MeSsaGe if you cAN read it
>  comE and gEt HEr.

Note that

> the second "I" in MILLION is not actually from the font the rest of the letter is.

I was not able to do anything yet with this information. In particular,

> just taking the  capitalized letters wasn't helpful by itself, nor  ROT-13ed.

Answer (score 1):

Is your girlfriend in

> Palestine?

After trying to solve this for minutes, the only thing I came up with was:

> The lines under the word "to" led to find [this documentary](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4662146/), which takes place in Palestine

Comment: Interesting thought process, not the answer I was looking for though. Thanks for pointing that out btw, forgot Word pointed out grammar-y stuff. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Is your girlfriend:

> Dead?

My explaination:

> The " I " in million is replaced with a character very similar to the Chinese symbol for earth i.e. dead and buried

Comment: Also nice logic, neat fact I didn't know! But no, also not really what I was looking for.

Comment: Am I on the right track? (with the symbol that is)

Comment: Sorta. You have the right idea with looking at the words, just not looking in the right ways.

Comment: Also, what is the name of the font? (so I can play with capital letters?)

Comment: Earwig Factory. It's not official; I downloaded it from somewhere because it's the best-looking ransom note-y font I found.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'd say she's

> In the Church

Explanation:

> Cause It says it right there. And from ZachThePilot's answer, She'd probably be in an underground somewhere there. Go there with some cops :)